# Freeform: Change field conditions between multi-page forms

Tags: craft3, plugin-freeform, freeform

I'm trying to only show some fields on *Page 2*, if a condition from a `<select>` box is met on *Page 1*. However, when I add Field Rules, I only have access to fields from the same page of the form.

I can manually override this in the templates, but, is there not a way to bring in fields from another page for a condition to be true/false? For instance: if this is a sign up form, and there are different account types to choose from, can a checkbox group only appear on Page 2 if that account type was chosen on Page 1?

Note: I'm running **Freeform 3.4.0** on a **Craft 3.3.2** install.

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Comment: @foamcow unfortunately not. We found a different UX to step around the issue, which was a bummer.

Comment: This would be useful.